# Ajax Get Url is not Responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get some XML file from the net and i need to display that in my html page......
This is how my javascript file looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".update").append("<ul></ul>");
           $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "https://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~xing/Lib/Docs/jaxp/docs/tutorial/sax/samples/slideSample01.xml",
           dataType: "xml",
           success: function(xml){
                    $(xml).find('slide').each(function(){
                      var sTitle = $(this).find('title').text();
                      //var sPublisher = $(this).find('heading').text();
                      $("<li></li>").html(sTitle + ", " + "sPublisher").appendTo(".update ul");
                    });
                  },
           error: function() {
                    alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
                  }
          });
 });
```

When i try to run this using this URL the browser gives an error saying "An error occurred while processing XML file"........................
But if i download the XML File and write it as following.... It will run the page without any errors.......

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "data.xml",
     dataType: "xml",
...................................
```

I also tried to use another online XML File same thing happened...... Anyone has an idea how to solve this???
Thank You!!!!!

Comment: You need CORS access to send data to that URL.

Comment: Read up on [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: thanks!! i'll have a look...